# Vue 3 access object property by variable name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vue-component, vuejs3

I am passing this from the parent as a prop

```
table_fields: [
    {label: 'Var 1', field: 'var_1'},
    {label: 'Var 2', field: 'var_2'},
    {label: 'Var 3', field: 'var_3'},
    {label: 'Var 4', field: 'var_4'},
    {label: 'Var 5', field: 'var_5'},
],
```

in the child component I am doing this

```
<table id="companiesList" class="table table-sm table-stripedd table-borderless table-hover table-responsivev">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-type="text" v-for="tableField in tableFields"  :key="tableField">{{tableField.label}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody v-if="date_loaded">
        <tr  v-for="single in data.data" :key="single.DUNS">
            <td v-for="tableField in tableFields" :key="tableField">{{single.tableField.label}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody v-else>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12" class="text-center">Loading...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here I am getting data from an API call.

The table header is as expected, but not sure how to get value from API data in the loop.

I tried this:

> `{{single.tableField.label}}` : Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
>
> `{{single.{{tableField.label}}}}` : Parsing error

Wat I want is to get data which is like `{{single.var_1}}`

How to achieve this?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *bracket notation* to access a variable property name of `single`, otherwise the code looks for a property whose name is the string `tableField`, which doesn't exist:

```html
<td v-for="tableField in tableFields" :key="tableField.label">
  {{ single[tableField.label] }}
</td>
```

When using *dot notation*, the segments are taken as literal property names.  when using *bracket notation*, the expression inside the brackets is evaluated for the property name.